# I cannot send email by SMTP in Laravel, but only in sendmail mail driver

Tags: laravel, smtp, sendmail

I cannot send email from my SMTP. I keep getting this error everytime my website sending an email.

The error is gone after I change the mail driver to `"sendmail"`. This is the error I got if I use SMTP as my mail driver:

```
ErrorException in EsmtpTransport.php line 289:
Call to undefined method setBcc
in EsmtpTransport.php line 289
at HandleExceptions->handleError('256', 'Call to undefined method setBcc', '/home/goframe/public_html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php', '289', array('method' => 'setBcc', 'args' => array('sales@goframe.id'), 'handler' => object(Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler)))
at trigger_error('Call to undefined method setBcc', '256') in EsmtpTransport.php line 289
at Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->__call('setBcc', array('sales@goframe.id')) in Setting.php line 43
at Setting::setMailFrom('support@goframe.id', '') in PasswordReset.php line 37
at PasswordReset->build()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PasswordReset), 'build'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(PasswordReset), 'build')) in Mailable.php line 109
at Mailable->send(object(Mailer)) in Mailer.php line 192
at Mailer->send(object(PasswordReset)) in MailableMailer.php line 99
at MailableMailer->send(object(PasswordReset)) in Member.php line 39
at Member->sendPasswordResetNotification('8add9f4862469b750e4d5fef31c64a32e23d51aa899e12fa4de1616f2ad95fd4') in PasswordBroker.php line 70
at PasswordBroker->sendResetLink(array('email' => 'ronaldsunrise@gmail.com')) in SendsPasswordResetEmails.php line 34
at MemberForgotPasswordController->sendResetLinkEmail(object(Request), 'id')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(MemberForgotPasswordController), 'sendResetLinkEmail'), array(object(Request), 'language' => 'id')) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('sendResetLinkEmail', array(object(Request), 'language' => 'id')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(MemberForgotPasswordController), 'sendResetLinkEmail') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
```

This my setting.php code :

```
namespace App\Helper;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class Setting
{
  const MAIL_SALES_NAME       = 'Goframe Sales';
  const MAIL_SALES_FROM       = 'sales@goframe.id';
  const MAIL_SALES_PASSWORD   = '**********';
  const MAIL_SUPPORT_NAME     = 'Goframe Support';
  const MAIL_SUPPORT_FROM     = 'support@goframe.id';
  const MAIL_SUPPORT_PASSWORD = '************';

  public static function get($name)
  {
    $ret = DB::select('SELECT `value` FROM settings WHERE `key` = ? LIMIT 1', [$name]);
    if (!$ret) throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Setting with name "'.$name.'" not found');
    return $ret[0]->value;
  }

  public static function setMailFrom($address, $password)
  {
    if (Config::get('mail.driver') != 'smtp') return;

    $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(
      Config::get('mail.host'), Config::get('mail.port'), Config::get('mail.encryption')
    );
    $transport->setUsername($address);
    $transport->setPassword($password);
    $transport->setBcc('sales@goframe.id');
    $transport->setBcc('accounting@goframe.id');
    $swift = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
    Mail::setSwiftMailer($swift);
  }

  public static function __callStatic($name, $args)
  {
    return self::get($name);
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Change `$message->setBcc('mybcc@email.com', 'My Name');` to `$message->bcc('mybcc@email.com', 'My Name');` || `setBcc` to `bcc`

Comment: Sorry, but it still same error with bcc.